# How to get user input stored in a variable in Visual Studio 2015 MVC

Tags: c#, user-input

Trying to move from PHP/HTML to C#/Visual Studio 2015, ASP.net Web Application and it is all new and challenging.
I am having problem figuring out how to ask for user input, storing the value in a variable when creating codes for web application. Thanks for any help or pointers.

Comment: This question is extremely broad.  You should try to narrow the question down to one particular issue you are having, and include example code of what you have tried.

Comment: Okay. Thx for reply. to simply put it, I need to prompt the user in a web page and store the response in a variable.

Comment: Put textbox in an HTML form, add a means for the user to post back, access value in that textbox?

Comment: So in PHP I could have : <input type='text' name='v1' value='Age'> and than I would have $v1 as a variable that I could work with. How is it in C#?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, you pass all of your data to the View in a ViewModel. So you would have, say:

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public string V1 { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the View, you would set your model type:

```
@model MyNamespace.HomeIndexViewModel
```

...which allows you to use it for rendering:

```
<input type="text" name="V1" value="Age">
```

When you call your View from the Controller, pass in a HomeIndexViewModel object:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new HomeIndexViewModel { V1 = "some string" });
}
```

Comment: Great. I'll take it from here. Thx.